# Why is the parent class method called?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, covariance

Why is the parent class method called when I am creating a child object. This is not even a static method.

```
class Parent {
    public String pubMethod(Integer i) {
        return "p";
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public String pubMethod(int i) {
        return "c";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent u = new Child();
        System.out.println(u.pubMethod(1));  // Prints "p"   why??
    }   
}
```

Here I am passing a primitive `int` . Still it goes to the parent method.

Any explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `u.pubMethod(1)`, the compiler considers only the signatures of the methods of `Parent` class, since `Parent` is the compile-type type of `u`. Since `public String pubMethod(Integer i)` is the only method of `Parent` having the required name, that's the selected method. `public String pubMethod(int i)` of `Child` class is not considered as a candidate, since `Parent` has no method of such signature.

In run-time, the method of the sub-class, `public String pubMethod(int i)`, cannot override the super-class method `public String pubMethod(Integer i)`, since it has a different signature. Therefore the `Parent` class method is executed.

In order for the `Child` class to be executed, you must either change its signature to match the `Parent` class method's signature, which will allow it to override the `Parent` class method:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public String pubMethod(Integer i) {
        return "c";
    }
}
```

Or you can add a second method to the `Parent` class, which the existing `Child` class method will override:

```
class Parent {
    public String pubMethod(Integer i) {
        return "pInteger";
    }
    public String pubMethod(int i) {
        return "pint";
    }
}
```

In the first case, the compiler will still have a single method to choose - `public String pubMethod(Integer i)` - but in run-time the `Child` class method will override it.

In the second case, the compiler will have two methods to choose from. It will choose `public String pubMethod(int i)`, since the type of the literal `1` is `int`. In run-time, the `Child` class `public String pubMethod(int i)` method will override it.

Comment: But since child class has method access from both his parent class and his own class. What I have read before is `" during execution it tries to find the match with the same argument type and if not found then only it goes for autoboxing"`. Isn't it right?

Comment: Yes, Nicky, but the variable `u` is of type `Parent`, not of type `Child`, so it can't be used to access the methods of `Child`, except for those that are genuine overrides of methods in `Parent`.

Comment: @Nicky It's right (regarding auto-boxing), but the compile time type of `u` is `Parent`, so the compiler doesn't consider the Child class methods as candidates, and therefore it must do auto-boxing, since it has only one candidate method, and that method requires auto-boxing.

Answer (score -1):

I think you didnt create your child object properly, you have:

```
Parent child = new Child();
```

But you should have:

```
Child child = new Child();
```

Comment: it's unclear what you meant by 'properly', both create an object properly